# Refreshing App.config after modifying bindingRedirect

Tags: winforms, configuration, .net-4.0

I'm working with WinForms a project that has a couple of oddball requirements. This is an existing business system that is installed in numerous locations under a fairly wide variety of environments. Part of this variety is a mixture of SQL Server versions, and--of particular importance--SQL Server Reporting Services versions. Everyone is on at least 2005, but about 50% of our users are on some flavor of 2008.

Unfortunately for me, I need to be able to run a client-side report that's written in 2008-version RDL. I can't modify the report in any substantive way at this point, so rewriting it in 2005-version RDL isn't an option. The catch is that this report (as it's written in 2008) requires the 2008 `ReportViewer` control. However, the 2008 `ReportViewer` control cannot connect to 2005 SSRS.

The solution that I've come up with is more than a little hacky, but it will alleviate 90% of the problems introduced. I've left the references pointing to the 2005 version of `ReportViewer`, and I'm modifying the application configuration on startup to add assembly binding redirection tags moving from version 9.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.0 for `ReportViewer.Common` and `ReportViewer.WinForms` if the user's target report server is running 2008.

As twitch-inducing as this solution is, it's working for me. The users running SSRS 2005 can still access their existing reports, just not the new one. The users running SSRS 2008 can access everything. My only problem is that I haven't been able to find a way to refresh the configuration data. I'm updating this info before any of the assemblies are loaded, but calling `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("runtime")` doesn't appear to have any effect. Once the app restarts, the proper assemblies are loaded, but I'd really like to be able to have this change take effect immediately.

Any thoughts on how I can force the runtime to reload the binding redirection information from the `App.config` file at runtime?

Comment: Not going to post a solution, but I think [this post on how to modify *.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918565/updating-appname-config-file-from-an-custom-installer-class-action) may help. They do so from an installer class, but same premise. or you can use XmlDocument and modify the values based on node location.

Comment: @Brad: Thanks, but modifying the file itself is not the issue; I have that done and working (I'm using the actual `System.Configuration` classes in combination with the new XLinq classes, incidentally). The issue here is that I'm modifying the file for the currently running application (instead of in another app, such as an `Installer` action would be) and can't seem to get the runtime to pick up on my updated values until after restarting.

Comment: Sorry, I saw the OpenExeConfiguration and the direct XML editing and thought it would work for your intent. According to [this post on egghead](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31133448/configurationmanager-refreshsection-not-refreshing.aspx) however, they say it wont refresh until you perform a get. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @Brad: Unfortunately, the runtime is what reads these values, not my code. From what Hans is saying, it sounds like the configuration info is read once and cached (which obviously makes sense), so no matter what it has after I change it, it won't be reflected until a restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the AppDomain is created, the configuration data that affects binding is fixed.  Which happens on the default CLR when the primary AD is created, before your code starts running.  If you are really desperate then you could create a secondary AppDomain and give it a custom AppDomainSetup with another ConfigurationFile.  And loads and run your regular startup code in that AD.  Not exactly sure what kind of side effects this might have.

Comment: Thanks, that's kinda what I was afraid of. If I have to jump through hoops like that, I'll just display a message to the user if the settings have to change and restart the app. I was just hoping to have it be a little more seamless than that.